# In App Billing - Android Application

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I want to create an android application (not yet registered on google play) and i want to implement in-app billing using mobile payments. Is it possible to implement them without uploading it to google play ?

example: 
easy2pay (http://easy2pay.co) 
 
centili (https://www.centili.com/payment-library) 
boku (http://www.boku.com)

if you can add another, please give me another one :)